# Short hand way to evaluate args in ruby

Tags: ruby, args

I am currently using the following code in a ruby program to evaluate variable length arguments that are passed to a method. The program is running however I'm wondering if there is a short hand way to write this.
Should have been more specific in my original description, trying to rewrite the Inject method for the Array class (hence the witty name...)

Therefore it needs to be able to accept a maximum of two args, and a minimum 0 if a block is given.

- array.inject(:+)
- array.inject{ |output, num| output + num }
- array.inject(arg, :+)
- array.inject(arg) { |output, num| output + num    }

The most difficult case/s to handle are the first and forth where the 1 arg can be either a Fixnum or a Symbol. As mentioned, the code works, just looking for ways to tidy it up.

```
class Array

  def enjict(*args)

    if args.length == 2 && args[0].is_a?(Fixnum) && args[1].is_a?(Symbol)
      start, symbol = args
    elsif args.length == 1
      raise ArgumentError unless args.first.is_a?(Symbol) || args.first.is_a?(Fixnum)
      symbol = args.first if args.first.is_a?(Symbol)
      start = args.first if args.first.is_a?(Fixnum)
    else
      raise ArgumentError unless block_given?
    end

    copiedArray = dup

    start = copiedArray.shift unless start

    if block_given?
      copiedArray.each { |num| start = yield(start, num) }
    else
      copiedArray.each { |num| start = start.send(symbol, num) }
    end
    start
  end
end
```

Comment: The only way I can see is actually creating multiple methods for the different arguments.

Comment: Can you make a short note on what you are trying to do with the method or the purpose of the method?

Comment: `start = copiedArray.shift` is executed if `start` is not assigned a value earlier. Is that your intent?  You'll get an argument error if  `block_given => false` and `symbol` has not been assigned a value earlier.  Please explain.  `copiedArray = dup` suggests this code is within a class. Is there anything we need to know about that class?  More generally, it would be helpful to understand what you are trying to accomplish.  I can see ways to clean up the code, but more information is needed.

Comment: Trying to rewrite the Inject method; updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sad truth is: it's messy, and there's nothing you can do about it. Almost all Ruby implementations implement `Enumerable#inject` with privileged access to the interpreter internals, including introspection of the arguments. MRI, YARV, MRuby implement it in C, MacRuby and RubyMotion in Objective-C, XRuby and JRuby in Java, Ruby.NET and IronRuby in C#, Topaz in RPython, Cardinal in PIR, and so on.

This is something that is simply not available to Ruby code.

Only [Rubinius](http://Rubini.us/) implements it [in Ruby](https://github.com/rubinius/rubinius/blob/master/kernel/common/enumerable.rb#L299-333).

You can use a similar trick by (ab)using the fact that the default argument expression for an optional parameter can be *any* arbitrarily complex Ruby expression and that local variables of those expressions become local variables of the method. This is a common trick for figuring out whether an argument was passed or not:

```
def inject(initial=(no_initial = true; nil), sym=(no_sym = true; nil))
  sym, initial = initial, nil if !block_given && no_sym
  # and so on …
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the conditions, how about refactoring your method arguments to:

```
def enjict(start, symbol, *options, &block)
  e = proc{ raise ArgumentError if options.length > 0 && !block_given? }
  e.call

  if start.is_a?(Fixnum) && symbol.is_a?(Symbol)
    # do something you want
  else
    e.call
  end
end
```

Comment: This takes 2 or more arguments, whereas the behavior the OP is trying to replicate takes 0, 1, or 2 but not more than 2 arguments.